# textarea:focus with opacity not working

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I can't find the answer anywhere on the net.

In my project, I want to have a picture and when hovering it, I want a textarea to appear with some text. This part is working very well.

The part that bug me is that I also want it to stay at opacity:1 when the cursor is focused in the textarea.

I want to achieve this using CSS only if possible.

I am able to have the textarea:focus work since I can make it change the background color easily.

Here's the JS Fiddle to show you all:
http://jsfiddle.net/X7Qu6/

HTML:

```
<div class="charpicture">
    <div class="BACKGROUNDdiv"><span class="BACKGROUNDtitle">Background</span>
        <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales erat justo, nec fermentum mauris tristique vitae. Sed dignissim dapibus imperdiet. Morbi blandit in mi ac tincidunt. Donec at purus. </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.charpicture:hover .BACKGROUNDdiv,
.BACKGROUNDdiv:hover{opacity:1;}
.BACKGROUNDdiv textarea:focus{background:green;opacity:1;}
```

Comment: if div has opacity:0; whatever is inside will be unseen

Comment: The original opacity is 0 since I don't want it to be seen unless I hover or focus it.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. You want the text area to fade in and out when the cursor hovers in and out. But when you click inside the text area, you want it to remain visible whether or not the cursor is in the text area. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. This is exactly what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textarea is inside BACKGROUNDdiv, so when it's hidden (`opticity:0`), there is no option to make any of its content visible. Textarea and your background have to be independent. Overlapping can be achieved with some relative/absolute positioning.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/X7Qu6/1/

Is that what you was looking for?

Comment: Some Cascading logic I missed. Thank you!